# graphQL _st_d_within doesn't return the correct distance

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, postgresql, graphql

I have a list of events, every event has a point. I want to return the events that are 35,000 meters from a certain point.
I use graphQL and this is the query:

```
events(where: {custom_data_locations: {point: {_st_d_within: {distance: 35000, from: {type: Point, coordinates: [31.8137167,34.6511933]}}}}})
  { date
    custom_data_locations{
    point
  }
```

But the problem is that _st_d_within also return points with a slightly larger distance, up to 39,000. I tried to set use_spheroid: true or use_spheroid: false but it still the same. How can I get only the points with the exact match?